# Fluent ui nortstar increase the size of icons

Tags: microsoft-teams, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

How do we override the styles of the icon ?. (apart from the size props of icon size="largest")
tried the below :

```
const myTheme: ThemeInput = {   componentStyles: {   EmojiSadIcon
    : {
          root: {
            width:100,
            height:100
          },
      }   }}
```

as well tried to give in styles

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your ask?

Comment: Could you please share some minimal code to repro the issue?

Comment: import React from "react";
import { QnaIcon } from "@fluentui/react-icons-northstar";
import {Provider,mergeThemes,teamsTheme,ThemeInput} from "@fluentui/react northstar";
const myTheme: ThemeInput = {
  componentStyles: {
    QnaIcon: {
      root: {
        height: "30px",
        width: "30px"
      }
    }
  }
};

const Example = () => (
  <Provider theme={mergeThemes(teamsTheme, myTheme)}>
    <QnaIcon />
  </Provider>
);

export default Example;

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to increase the size of icons apart from the size props of icon.